# Соединяем Java c C++ в qt через QAndroidJniObject

Tags: java, c++, qt, jni, кроссплатформенность

Подскажите как соединить Java c C++ в qt через QAndroidJniObject?

это мой  `.pro`

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2020-12-15T20:16:21
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui


@
android{
QT += androidextras
}
@

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

DISTFILES += \
    Jamba.java
```

это mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QAndroidJniObject>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Это мой mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("org.qtproject.example.MainActivity", "startFacebookActivity", "()V");

}
```

Это мой `Jamba.java`

```
public class Jamba {


static public void startFacebookActivity() {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
}


}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> D:\Programs\Qt\Units\examples\untitled\mainwindow.h:5: ошибка: C1083:
> Cannot open include file: 'QAndroidJniObject': No such file or
> directory

Делал по документации : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть?

Comment: Похоже вы пытаетесь использовать враппер для ART в приложении на windows.

Comment: Получается, что мой подход невозможен?

Comment: я в прошлом вопросе уже написал, что проще будет сделать отдельное java приложение.